# Using Terminal with a serial connection

Tags: terminal, macos, c

Hello I am using terminal to output my serial connection device. I was wondering how can I get rid of the spaces when it starts a new line. On Windows I would use Putty and turn on Implicit CR in every LF and it would get rid of this issue. Is there an alternative to this setting on terminal or another program to use other than the terminal? I'm new to coding on MacBook. Thank you! [image]

Comment: How do you start the terminal? what command do you use to show data? (Note: default on terminal it is to use both CR and LF [there are two characters because terminals! they were slow to move head back and move paper], but there are options). Check `stty` command (icrnl, ocrnl options).

Comment: I use screen [device name] [baud rate].

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi's answer is correct, you'll need the said flags of `stty`. If you need more info, this phenomenon is commonly referred to as "staircase effect", you'll find many websearch results for this term.

Comment: I will research it thank you!